# Count Specific Days of Week in Time Period

Tags: oracle, function, date

I am trying to find the number of Xdays (Mondays, Fridays, etc.) in a month. I could always loop through days within a month, find their day of week, sum it up, and store it, but I think there's a better way to do that.

Ideally I'd like to get a result for "how many mondays, tuesdays, and fridays (or whatever days) in September 2015?".

I can find how to get week days in a time period. I can get this kind of information from dates already entered in the database, but I want to know there's a Tuesday, even if there isn't data for that day.

Comment: You could probably write a script that checks what the first day of the month is, and how many days are in the month and extrapolate from there.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of Michiel T's answer, using `trunc` with the month format parameter to get the first day of the month:

```
select count(*)
from
  (select trunc(sysdate, 'MM') + (level - 1) dt
   from dual
   connect by level <= extract(day from last_day(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'))))
where to_char(dt, 'FMDAY') = 'MONDAY'
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterative approach, based on PL/SQL [`PIPELINED` functions](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=207):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE days_tbl AS TABLE OF DATE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION days_for_month(basedate IN DATE)
RETURN days_tbl PIPELINED
AS
    month VARCHAR(2);
    thedate DATE := TRUNC(basedate,'MON');
BEGIN
    LOOP
      PIPE ROW(thedate);
      EXIT WHEN thedate = LAST_DAY(thedate);
      thedate := thedate + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Basic usage:

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
  FROM TABLE(days_for_month(SYSDATE)) 
  WHERE TO_CHAR(COLUMN_VALUE,'FMDAY') = 'MONDAY';
```

The function might have been optimized to your specific needs (find a given day by name), but keeping it more generic allows some usage flexibility like:

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
  FROM TABLE(days_for_month(SYSDATE)) 
  WHERE TO_CHAR(COLUMN_VALUE,'FMDAY') IN ('SUNDAY','SATURDAY');
```

---

Given your example:

> "how many mondays, tuesdays, and fridays (or whatever days) in September 2015?".

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM TABLE(days_for_month(TO_DATE('09-2015','MM-YYYY'))) 
  WHERE TO_CHAR(COLUMN_VALUE,'FMDAY') IN ('MONDAY','TUESDAY','FRIDAY');
```

Producing:

```
COUNT(*)
13
```

Or if you need details:

```
SELECT T.D, COUNT(*)
  FROM TABLE(days_for_month(TO_DATE('09-2015','MM-YYYY'))),
       (SELECT 'MONDAY' AS D FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 'TUESDAY' FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 'FRIDAY' FROM DUAL) T
  WHERE TO_CHAR(COLUMN_VALUE,'FMDAY') = T.D
  GROUP BY T.D
```

To produce:

```
D       COUNT(*)
TUESDAY 5
FRIDAY  4
MONDAY  4
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the first Tuesday in a given month:

```
NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(DATE '2014-09-19', 'MM')-1, 'TUESDAY')
```

This gives you the last Tuesday in a given month:

```
NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE '2014-09-19')-7, 'TUESDAY')
```

So you can combine it to:

```
SELECT 1 + (NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE '2014-09-19')-7, 'TUESDAY') - NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(DATE '2014-09-19', 'MM')-1, 'TUESDAY'))/7 AS TUESDAYS_IN_MONTH
FROM dual;
```

Comment: you may wish to check this for all days. It does not give the correct answer for Mondays in September 2014.

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle, you can use the date-format masks to see what day a certain date is. The following example counts all Monday's in month 9 (September) of 2015

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   ( SELECT RTRIM(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(LEVEL, '09')||'09'||'2015','DDMMYYYY'),'DAY')) AS days
         FROM dual
         WHERE ROWNUM <= EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('09'||'2015','MMYYYY')))
         CONNECT BY LEVEL=ROWNUM
       )
WHERE  days = 'MONDAY'
       ;
```

Answer (score -2):

as @Leeish said:

> "You could probably write a script that checks what the first day of
>   the month is, and how many days are in the month and extrapolate from
>   there"

(I only have access to MS Sql but should be similar)

this will get you the first day of the month in Text format ('Monday' for example):

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

this will get you how many days are in the month:

```
select datediff(d,  GETDATE(), dateadd(m, 1,  GETDATE()))
```

hope this helps.

Comment: `DATEDIFF`, `DATENAME`, `GETDATE` are not Oracle functions.